# Using a recoded window 10 days back in a GAM-model, is that a double whammy or is it OK to do?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, moving-window

I'm formulating a prediction in a logistic reression type in a GAM model.

```
model1 <- gam(hi.lo.arousal ~ s(time) + s(mssd) + s(sum10days),
              family = binomial)
```

I wish to predict high arousal in bipolar patients, on the basis of earlier arousal. I have daily Hi/lo measures of arousal in a timeseries. These are made from variables coded 0-5 and then transformed to be hi or lo ((4 or more vs. less than 4) instead. The covariates I wish to use in my model is time spent in treatment,  variability in scores (root of mean succesive squared differences), summation of the 0-5 values in arousal over the last 10 days. In formulating my model,  in a way I wish to use the autocorrelation as a predictor. Im wondering if I recode my variables in a way that I in each row get summed values of the previous 10 rows (a window of the last 10 days) would I be smoothing she smooth, or is this ok to do this mathematically when making a gam?
My thinking is: The covariates I use will give me an indication of whether patient time spent in therapy, previous variability in emotion & previous "pain" last ten days has a say in whether my patients loose their temper.The following days.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question has been pending for som days now, I'll answer as far as I hav got for now:
1) The smoothing of the smooth is probably not a problem since I can control the wigglyness of the curve by degrees of freedom / number of "knots" on the smoothed curve.
2) I can read the degree of autocorrelation in the p-value returned for the sum of "TRUE"-answers (level is 4 or above) over the last 10 days.